# SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter android - how to add some actions in header

Tags: android

SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter android - how to add  some actions in header like hide favorites

Comment: SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter is not a standard android component.  Post what you have tried, add more context to the question, and state the specific problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you naveed actually I need two headers in recycle view like "favorities" and "All"  and a toggle button for hide/show those . i used two recycle views  and inside a nested scroll view but in that case, initial loading there is some delay due to the repeated calling of view holder